# Rails wicked gem - bootstrap modal on finish wizard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, wicked-gem

I have searched over the stackoverflow and internet but could not find a solution.

I have a car modal and I used wicked gem for user to enter data. But on the finish wizard, I would like to show bootstrap modal to user that kind of says, "we have received your car listing request. We will review and get back to you".

Is it technically possible?. The problem is, when a user wants to edit his/her car listing I use the same wicked form.

So if it is possible, how should I understand it is first listing request and he/she is not editing the car modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the same wizard controller rather use a different controller to do your crud for car model (ie CarsController). This will save you some pain as the functionality will probably diverge down the line (ie have more or less fields for edit or have it in different format). You can refactor your views to use common partials for reuse.